# Async Web Api does not release the thread to another request

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, async-await

The code below does not release IIS threads for new requests, why?

```
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    await Task.Delay(15000);
}
```

I'm using Windows 10, .Net Framework 4.7, no changes to the Default AppPool (single IIS worker process) on an i7:
[image]

Using performance counters, I can see that 6 out of my 16 parallel CURL requests get queued, while my CPU is free (20% usage).

[image]

Comment: The thread pool on asp.net by default is tuned differently on server OSes vs workstation OSes. Try running the same test on a server OS.

Comment: This code does not work on the server side, if you want to increase iis worker process, you can refer to this link: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/cpu).

Comment: IIS on client OSes has a limit on the number of concurrent requests. Try running the same test on a server OS.